# RxSwift Skip Events Until Own Sequence has finished

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I have one observable (we will call it trigger) that can emit many times in a short period of time. When it emits I am doing a network Request and the I am storing the result with the scan Operator.

My problem is that I would like to wait until the request is finished to do it again. (But as it is now if trigger emits 2 observables it doesn't matter if fetchData has finished or not, it will do it again)

Bonus: I also would like to take only the first each X seconds (Debounce is not the solution because it can be emitting all the time and I want to get 1 each X seconds, it isn't throttle neither because if an observable emits 2 times really fast I will get the first and the second delayed X seconds)

The code:

```
trigger.flatMap { [unowned self] _ in
        self.fetchData()
        }.scan([], accumulator: { lastValue, newValue in
        return lastValue + newValue
    })
```

and fetchData:

```
func fetchData() -> Observable<[ReusableCellVMContainer]>
```

trigger:

```
let trigger = Observable.of(input.viewIsLoaded, handle(input.isNearBottomEdge)).merge()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish in my answer below.

The operator that will achieve what you want is `flatMapFirst`. This will ignore events from the trigger until the `fetchData()` is complete.

```
trigger
    .flatMapFirst { [unowned self] _ in
        self.fetchData()
    }
    .scan([], accumulator: { lastValue, newValue in
        return lastValue + newValue
    })
```

I'm leaving my previous answer below in case it helps (if anything, it has the "bonus" answer.)

---

The problem you are having is called "back pressure" which is when the observable is producing values faster than the observer can handle.

In this particular case, I recommend that you don't restrict the data fetch requests and instead map each request to a key and then emit the array in order:

```
trigger
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap { [unowned self] count, _ in
        Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(count), self.fetchData())
    }
    .scan(into: [Int: Value](), accumulator: { lastValue, newValue in
        lastValue[newValue.0] = newValue.1
    })
    .map { $0.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }).map { $0.value }}
```

To make the above work, you need this:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func enumerated() -> Observable<(Int, E)> {
        let shared = share()
        let counter = shared.scan(0, accumulator: { prev, _ in return prev + 1 })
        return Observable.zip(counter, shared)
    }
}
```

This way, your network requests are starting ASAP but you aren't loosing the order that they are made in.

---

For your "bonus", the `buffer` operator will do exactly what you want. Something like:

```
trigger.buffer(timeSpan: seconds, count: Int.max, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { $0.first }
```